Power Automate Deleting All Tasks
I have a SharePoint List that handles critical notifications. I have a Power Automate flow set up to notify via e-mail when a new task is added but now I would like to create an automation to delete the task when it has been marked as Complete. To an extent, this automation works however it is deleting every task regardless of the status.
I can't find the problem. Can someone please assist? I am new to SharePoint automations.
Screenshots of flow attached at: https://imgur.com/a/vQBdsrz.

I'm hoping that your When an item is created is working as expected.
For the deletion, I would recommend using Filer Query to get all items with Status Completed, and then delete one item at a time. This would be a separate Schedule or Manually Trigger Power Automate.
See the screenshots below:


Filter Query


Delete Each Item with Completed Status



Hi - I don't see a "Manually Trigger a flow" in my triggers. Could that be because of licensing?

I don't think it's a license issue. What do you see when you do these steps: Sign in to Power Automate => From the navigation bar on the left, => select My flows =>Select New flow ? You should see options: Automated cloud flow, Instant cloud flow, Scheduled cloud flow, and Desktop flow. You need to select Instant cloud flow to trigger manually

Ok, I was doing an automated flow. I will try an Instant flow;  now, when I do this will I need to run it manually as the name implies or will it still be run automatically?

For testing purpose, run it manually to see if that works. Then, once you are satisfied with the results, delete (right click on it to see delete option) the Manually trigger a flow at the top, and it will then allow Add a trigger option to add Schedule (Recurrence) trigger. You then can schedule it as your need.

Ok thank you. I will give this a shot tomorrow and I'll update here success or failure.
